# Drupal 7: Custom fields in "Menu tree" views

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, custom-fields

I have a view (Menu tree) it shows the list of menu titles and descriptions from specific menu section and I want to add thumb image for each menu item in this view, I'm using "menuimage" module to attach images to menu items but when editing view and trying to add a new field (Menu image) there is no such field in fields list.

I'm new in Drupal and maybe there is more simple way for doing this.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: When you say you have a view , are you talking about the "views" module ? When you say "Menu tree" are you talking about the "Menu tree" module? I'm confused.

Comment: Yes it's views 3 module, but there is no module menu tree it's built in view type